# value of 'this' being destroyed by listener

Tags: javascript, this, event-listener

I have the following functions:

```
function moveDown(event) {
  const submenus = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu')
  var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");

  var sub

  if (event.target.innerHTML === "ABOUT US") {
    sub = submenus[0]
  } else {
    sub = submenus[1]
  }

  var rect = sub.getBoundingClientRect();
  navbar.style.marginBottom = rect.height + "px"
}


function moveUp(event) {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");
  navbar.style.marginBottom = 0
}
```

both of those are fine. Can someone explain why 'this' is being destroyed with the following:

```
(function() {
  var takeAction = document.getElementsByClassName('takeAction')[0]
  var aboutUs = document.getElementsByClassName('aboutUs')[0]

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    moveDown(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    moveDown(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    moveUp(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    moveUp(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  }) 
})()
```

but works properly if I do:

```
(function() {
  var takeAction = document.getElementsByClassName('takeAction')[0]
  var aboutUs = document.getElementsByClassName('aboutUs')[0]

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', moveDown,{passive: false})
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseover',moveDown,{passive: false})

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseleave', moveUp,{passive: false})
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseleave',moveUp,{passive: false}) 
})()
```

Why does passing the event into an anonymous and then passing it to moveDown cause a different value for 'this' as opposed to just calling moveDown directly.

NOTE: in the second example moveDown and moveUp have no arguments.

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how a function is invoked. An event listener add via `addEventListener` is always invoked such that `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to. But `func()` will set `this` to either `undefined` or the global object depending on strict mode. That being said, your code doesn't use `this` so not sure what the issue is? Or what do you mean with "this is being destroyed"?

Comment: @Felix Kling, in the first way I call it the mouseover effect works for the takeAction element but not the aboutUs.  In the second way it works for both. As you said, I'm not using 'this' but don't understand why the first method doesn't work